# specify meta_key / meta_value condition for prev_post_link and next_post_link

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I've got a custom post type (CPT) called `event`. Every event has got an associated `meta_key` called `event_date`.

I want to make sure that events with empty `event_date` won't appear in my list of all events and in the prev/next event navigation when viewing a single event. I also want to order events by the `event_date` meta_key.

I managed to exclude events with empty `event_date` and order them correctly in the overall list of events by hooking into `pre_get_posts` hook.

Is it possible to hook into `prev_post_link` and `next_post_link` functions to specify `meta_key` select condition and `meta_key` order condition without the plugin? Is there a hook for it?

[P.S. note]:
I also tried using [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/) plugin. I figured out how to order events by meta_key. However, the events with empty `event_date` meta_value are still appearing in the prev/next navigation when viewing a single event.

It doesn't seem to be possible to hook into WP before the plugin, because I think it constructs its own SQL. I could use `ex_posts` with the list of all the event ids to exclude, but that would mean extra query to the db.

Many thanks,
Dasha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/).

As to an empty `event_date` meta key - I have added some code to prevent a post from being saved if meta key value isn't correct.

Have a look at this posts:

1. [Modifying Wordpress post status on Publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007748/modifying-wordpress-post-status-on-publish)
2. [don't publish custom post type post if a meta data field isn't valid](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15546/dont-publish-custom-post-type-post-if-a-meta-data-field-isnt-valid)

Comment: What was your "some code" in this case? Its a very valid question, but no concrete answer.

Answer (score 1):

prev and next_post_link ultimately call the [get_adjacent_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post) function to query the db, which has filterable $join $where and $sort vars.

Comment: thanks. I've been trying to find an example of their usage without any luck. Also, I can't figure out how to hook into the `get_adjacent_post` to check if my SQL is constructed correctly.

Comment: I posted my working filters here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/139469/28957