# Adjust query on single

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, metabox, post-meta

I am building an event manager. One of the template files I have is events-single.php which displays single events. At the bottom of this I have next and previous events using `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link`. The problem is that those functions proceed through the events in order of **published date** rather than **event date**. (I have a meta key `_fulldate` setup on the CPT for this). When I was building events-archive.php file I overcame a similar problem by doing something like this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 
'post_type' => 'events', 
'orderby' => 'meta_value', 
'meta_key' => '_fulldate', 
'order' => 'ASC')
);
```

However when I try that on events-single.php it makes all the events display on the page.

Ultimatly I want events-single.php to behave like a single page but then allow me control over the query as above. Is this possible or will I have to do a second loop for the Previous and Next links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: [specify meta_key / meta_value condition for prev_post_link and next_post_link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15317/specify-meta-key-meta-value-condition-for-prev-post-link-and-next-post-link)

Which ultimately leads to this plugin, which accesses the get_adjacent_post function mentioned above: [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/)

And looks like it would fit your needs by allowing you to specificy a meta_value for the next/prev post hook.

Comment: Thanks for that link - it's the right track all right, but I'm not really understanding how to implement the filters and I cant find a full example anywhere. Anyway It looks to be a bit more complex than I want to get into at the moment and it's not a huge issue on the theme as in context I don't think previous next events will be that important to most people so I'm leaving it out for this version. BTW the theme is for resale so I want to avoid plugins.