# Dynamic next and previous post links

Tags: navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

Is there any way to change the next and previous post links dynamically.

By default the previous post link takes to the previous post. However I want it to link to some different post, that I posted way back in time. Similar with the next post link.

Currently I have manually setting the next and prev post links using javascript. **Can I achieve this with Wordpress (PHP)?**

Comment: Code you are using?

Comment: @Castiblanco, currently I am using script tag in each post to set next and prev variables. And after page load I am updating the next and prev DOM elements with the link and title.

Comment: This post can answer to your question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/139453/filter-next-post-link-and-previous-post-link-by-meta-key

Answer (score 0):

1) As you need to hide next or prev link you should output both.

2) Then create some meta field in posts. I usually use ACF for it, it is pretty easy. Create 2 custom fields, text input fields for every post, let's say:
"Next button URL" and "Prev button URL"

3) And in post.php wrap "previous" and "next" buttons created in #1 with if condition, for example:

```
if($nextcustomfield){
    echo '<a href="'.$nextcustomfield.'">NEXT</a>';
}else{
    NORMAL NEXT LINK CODE
}
```